# Network File sysetm : Files move/copy ie., Migration using java

Tags: java, nfs

Could anyone please share a sample program that show how to migrate or copy files from one location to another location which is in Network File Share .

Thanks in advance.
Sai Pavan

Comment: What type of share is it?

Comment: If share is like public or private, how to approach with different modes